# CQRS and commands debouncing

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, architecture, real-time, cqrs

I have the following task:

1. Our current architecture is Web SPA with CQRS and MVVM. We have
   commands, queries and SingnalR as message bus.
2. Users can select, move, resize divs on the same workspace from several web browsers simultaneously.
3. Each div is binded to the approprite ViewModel. Each ViewModel has it's own query to refresh. Each ViewModel subscribed to business events and refresh the whole state after it.

Lets image that User is doing the following steps:

1. Select div (SelectWidgetCommand sent)
2. Move div to x=10. (ChangePositionCommand sent)
3. Move div to x=100. (ChangePositionCommand sent)

The problem is that the commands are fire-and-forget and the User may receive event WidgetSelectedEvent during the Step 3 but the ChangePositionCommand may not be handled yet. So the User will receive the old x position and the div will move to the old position.

What is the best practice to handle this kind of issues?

What we are now doing is splitting the DivViewModel into two divs: SelectionViewModel, PositionViewModel. Each ViewModel has it's own query to refresh and different events to handle. Also we consider using debounce and rolling buffer for commands handling.

Comment: Your solution seems like a good one. Segregate into smaller models each synchronized through a specific subset of events. Another solution I could think of would be to have a single model, but create event-attribute mappings (e.g. map ViewModel.position to ChangePositionCommand.position). As long as your events are not received out of order that should work. Btw, it feels weird to have a selecton command handled server-side. Can't the selection state only exists on the client?

Comment: @plalx We have same selection for all users that work on one workspace

Comment: Isn't that creating unnecessary contention which almost prevents collaboration? What if the selection gets changed by user B while  user A was trying to perform a command on it's original selection?

Comment: @plalx we should handle such issues. If the selection event hasn't been got by User A then commands of User A should be raised against User A current selection.

Comment: This seems like a very problematic design. Why not simply get rid of the server-side selection? What does it bring? It only seems to harm collaboration. Otherwise the selection could change a split second before another issues a command and then the command would be raised against the wrong selection.

Comment: @plalx Maybe we really need to consider using another approach. I really liked the Greg Young's talk on occasionally connected system. Moving domain model to client is interesting. But I can't understand why the model remains on the server if only clients send command to offline state? And what should happen if we have both Web and Desktop App editing the same document? And what if some logic can't be handled in Client Machine due to security restrictions...

Comment: My comment really has nothing to do with being occasionally connected. My point is that a selection doesn't seem like an important business concept that should be part of the domain model. To me it's a UI thing, it's just a mechanism that allows the user to select the command targets. Removing the selection from the domain model simplifies it greatly and you dramatically reduce contention (selection was shared). Now every user can have their own local selection and no conflict will occur unless they touch the same document parts.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to review Greg Young's talk on [occasionally connected systems](https://skillsmatter.com/skillscasts/1980-cqrs-not-just-for-server-systems).

> The problem is that the commands are fire-and-forget

How do you understand "fire-and-forget"?  If the model isn't allowed to reject the commands that are dispatched to it, then the messages you are sending are *events*, not commands.

The usual implementation of the write model in CQRS is that commands are linearized (handled one at a time).  Commands are expected to ensure that their pre-conditions are met.

`Compare-And-Set`, rather than `Set`.

In its simplest form, the commands specify the initial version of the aggregate they are going to modify, in much the same way that conditional requests in HTTP specify [preconditions on the resource](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7232#section-3).  In the case of a race condition, with multiple commands trying to change the same part of the model, one command would win, and the loser would be trivially rejected.

Better (but more work to implement) would be to implement a sort of second chance for the losing command -- building into the model sufficient understanding that it can determine whether the changes induced by the two commands conflict.  If they don't, then you just chain them together.

An alternative approach is to allow both writes to happen, and accept that there is a conflict.  Think about the way a source control system works: I've committed history 1-2-X, you've committed history 1-2-Y, and now there are two alternatives until somebody reconciles them with a merge.

That approach is roughly in alignment with Udi Dahan's central point in his essay [Race Conditions Don't Exist](http://udidahan.com/2010/08/31/race-conditions-dont-exist/).

> A microsecond difference in timing shouldn’t make a difference to core business behaviors.

If your views are being built from lists of events (as you describe here), then one place to start with with a [CRDT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-free_replicated_data_type) of a list.  Mark Klepmann describes a [JSON data type](https://arxiv.org/abs/1608.03960) [(hacker new commentary)](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=12303100).  That doesn't get you "no conflicts", but it does get you the property that two users who see the same individual events necessarily seem them in the same order (if there is a problem, then everybody is seeing the same problem).

But Greg's approach is probably simpler to implement - authors work with a local copy of the shared model, and interact with it, but that shared model is an approximation, and commands that cannot be reconciled by the book of record are returned to the author for manual mitigation.

Comment: the problem is that my events doesn't contain data and I don't create ViewModels from events. When ViewModel receive the event it sends the query to refresh the whole state of ViewModel.